# Getting a list of Nuget Package Updates from a Build script

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I was looking at adding a line to the build script to pump in some text about any available package updates via nuget.  This is available via the Package Manager console by issuing a command such as:

```
 > Get-Package folderPath -Updates
```

Surprisingly, while I thought that a similar command would have been surfaced via the nuget console application, it is not!  Not really sure why they didn't surface all of the same functionality that is in the PowerShell API into the Console Tool!?

I'm no PowerShell guru, so what would be the best approach to running the command from the build script?  Can I call out to PowerShell easily, or would I look at building a utility which references NuGet.Core.dll direct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the console application as yet. We're looking at building out the NuGet command line tool into being a full NuGet client so it would have mostly the same features as the in process powershell.

You can build your own client today if you really wanted by referencing NuGet.Core and seeing what the cmdlets do you can easily figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for the response, pretty much what I expected.  I did take a look at NuGet.Core in Reflector but couldn't easily see which classes/methods to call to achieve this.  Can you give me any pointers pls?

Comment: PackageRepositoryExtensions.GetUpdates will give you a list of updates for a list of packages.
http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/54fb80904af6#src%2fCore%2fRepositories%2fPackageRepositoryExtensions.cs